# Methods with keywords from the instances's attributes

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, keyword-argument

The perfect, but impossible, scenario would be:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def foo(self, x = self.x, y = self.y):
        return x + y
```

It doesn't work because *self* isn't defined. I have done lots of research, looked on decorators, descriptors, metaclasses, almost everything. The solution may be the most obvious and known to all, but I couldn't find it. I could manage two workarounds, as follows:

```
def prep(argslist, argsprovided, attributes):
        argsout = []
        for name in argslist:
            if name in argsprovided:
                argsout.append(argsprovided[name])
            else:
                argsout.append(getattr(attributes,name))

        return argsout

class example(object):

    # I can create a default instance or a custom one
    def __init__(self,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

    # I can wrap a function to use the self argument       
    def wrapper(self):
        def foo(x = self.x, y = self.y, z = self.z, w = self.w):
            return x + y + z + w
        return foo

    # I can wrap 'joo' alongside with foo, and make 'wrapper' return a list    
    def joo(self, **kwargs):
        [x,y,z,w] = prep(['x','y','z','w'],kwargs,self)
        return x + y + z + 2*w

    # I can use my custom 'prep' function to to the job
    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        [x,y,z,w] = prep(['x','y','z','w'],kwargs,self)
        return x + y + z + w



# Creates a default instance and a custom one        
c = example()
d = example(2,2,2,2)

# I can use 'foo' with the instance's default values with both wrapping and 'prepping'
print(c.wrapper()())
print(d.wrapper()())
print(c.foo())
print(d.foo())

# I can use 'foo' with a mix of default values and provided values with both wrapping and 'prepping'
print(c.wrapper()(1,2,3))
print(d.wrapper()(1,2,3))
print(c.foo(y = 3,z = 4,w = 5))
print(d.foo(y = 3,z = 4,w = 5))
```

The code prints out:

```
4
8
4
8
7
8
13
14
```

I have a huge class with lots of functions, every one needs the behavior of 'foo'. My prep solution is too time consuming. After profiling the code, I figured it spent 12 seconds inside prep only. What is a clever and less time consuming way of doing this? I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will help but how about using None as a default value and use a clause to determine the value. For example:

```
def foo(self, x=None, y=None):
    real_x = x if x != None else self.x
    real_y = y if y != None else self.y
    return real_x + real_y
```

Comment: It is indeed faster! It's a good option, but some of my functions take over 10 arguments, so it's not that practicle. The wrapper method is just little bit slower. The best way is to define k = c.wrapper() and then use k().

Answer (score 0):

I found six ways of doing what I wanted. After profiling the code, the result was:

```
afoo     foo       noo1     noo2     wrap1     wrap2
6.730    28.507    3.98     4.097    10.256    3.468
6.407    28.659    4.096    3.924    9.783     3.529
6.277    28.450    3.946    3.889    10.265    3.685
6.531    30.287    3.964    4.149    10.077    3.674
```

As you will see ahead, `noo1`, `noo2` and `wap2` are quite similar on code. The conventional method `afoo` is not that efficient. My custom method `foo` is terrible and `wrap1` was just tested for the sake of completeness.

***afoo.py***
The drawback is that you need an extra line for each function argument.

```
class example(object):

    # I can create a default class or a custom one
    def __init__(self,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

    def afoo(self, x = None, y = None, z = None, w = None):
        x = x if x != None else self.x
        y = y if y != None else self.y
        z = z if z != None else self.z
        w = w if w != None else self.w
        return x + y + z + w


c = example(2,2,2,2)
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    c.afoo(1,2,3,4)
```

***foo.py***
This one is the slower method.

```
def prep(argslist, argsprovided, attributes):
        argsout = []
        for name in argslist:
            if name in argsprovided:
                argsout.append(argsprovided[name])
            else:
                argsout.append(getattr(attributes,name))

        return argsout

class example(object):

    # I can create a default class or a custom one
    def __init__(self,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        [x,y,z,w] = prep(['x','y','z','w'],kwargs,self)
        return x + y + z + w


c = example(2,2,2,2)
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    c.foo(x = 1,y = 2,z = 3,w = 4)
```

***wrapper1.py***
By far less efficient than `wrapper2.py`.

```
class example(object):

    # I can create a default class or a custom one
    def __init__(self,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

    def wrapper(self):
        def foo(x = self.x, y = self.y, z = self.z, w = self.w):
            return x + y + z + w
        return foo


c = example(2,2,2,2)
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    c.wrapper()(1,2,3,4)
```

***wrapper2.py***

```
class example(object):

    # I can create a default class or a custom one
    def __init__(self,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

    def wrapper(self):
        def foo(x = self.x, y = self.y, z = self.z, w = self.w):
            return x + y + z + w
        return foo


c = example(2,2,2,2)
k = c.wrapper()
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    k(1,2,3,4)
```

***noo1.py***

```
class example(object):

    # I can create a default class or a custom one
    def __init__(self,U,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

        def noo(x = self.x, y = self.y, z = self.z, w = self.w):
            return x + y + z + w

        self.noo = noo

c = example(2,2,2,2)
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    c.noo(1,2,3,4)
```

***noo2.py***

```
class example(object):

    # I can create a default class or a custom one
    def __init__(self,x = 1,y = 1,z = 1,w = 1):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w

    def __call__(self):
        def noo(x = self.x, y = self.y, z = self.z, w = self.w):
            return x + y + z + w

        self.noo = noo


c = example(2,2,2,2)
c()
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    c.noo(1,2,3,4)
```

When testing these codes I included the `prep` function in all of them, just to be shure they had the same basic structure, and thus the time difference would be from the loops.